# Reactjs: How to select one or multiple cards when clicked with a state hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I have a card component TemplateList that is used to map my template cards (I add them through an array).

I would like to add an onClick state hook functionality that helps me select one or multiple cards when clicked, How can I do this?

This is my TemplateList component:

```
import TemplateCard from 
import styles from "./styles/actionpage.m.css";

export type Template = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgURL: string;
};

type Props = {
    templates: Template[];
};

const TemplateList = ({ templates }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
            {templates.map((item) => (
                <TemplateCard
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    img={item.imgURL}
                    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default TemplateList;
```

This is my TemplateCard component:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles/cards.m.css";

type Props = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
    classNameToAdd?: string;
    selected?: boolean;
    classNameOnSelected?: string;
};

const TemplateCard = ({
    title,
    description,
    img,
    classNameToAdd,
    classNameOnSelected,
    selected,
}: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();
    let className = `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd}`;

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }

    return (
        <div style={card} className={className}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>{title}</div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

TemplateCard.defaultProps = {
    classNameOnSelected: styles.selected,
};

export default TemplateCard;
```

At the moment, I added a "selected" prop that gives my cards a border when true, but this of course selects all cards when true now.

This is how my cards are supposed to look like when selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To approach this, you have to give each card its own state; `selected`.
This way each card will have their own tiny logic through which they will know if they're selected or not.

```js
// TemplateCard.js
...

const TemplateCard = ({
    title,
    description,
    img,
    classNameToAdd,
    classNameOnSelected,
    /* selected,  we will make this a state instead of prop */
}: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false); // Added state

    // Added handler
    const handleClick = () => {
      setSelected(!selected);
    };

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }

    return (
        <div style={card} className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>{title}</div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
...
```

Comment: Great! I just added it and now it selects my cards as it should. I would have one questions though, I get this warning in my console and dont know why its happening:

Comment: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `TemplateList`. See react-warning-keys for more information.
    in TemplateCard (created by TemplateList)
    in TemplateList (created by ActionPageNew)

Comment: Whenever you render a list of react components via map method, you also have to provide a key prop to each React component. You can find more info on react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Answer (score 1):

Add an onClick handler on your TemplateCard component and fire it on the main div. Moreover you need some identification for your individual card so we can use the index of array its coming from.

Like this:

```
const TemplateCard = ({
    title,
    description,
    img,
    classNameToAdd,
    classNameOnSelected,
    selected,
    handleClick
    index
}: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();
    let className = `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd}`;

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }

    return (
        <div style={card} className={className} onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>{title}</div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In your TemplateList component, you need to set an array of indexes (using useState) that stores the indexes of clicked TemplateCards so you can check which card is selected and which is not. And set the state using the function which we passed onto the child component i.e. handleClick

Like this:

```
const [selectedArray,setSelectedArray]=useState([])

const handleClick=(i)=>{
const tempArray =[...selectedArray]
if(tempArray[i]==i){tempArray[i]=undefined}
else {tempArray[i]=i}

setSelectedArray(tempArray)
}
```

The component will be like this:

```
const TemplateList = ({ templates }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
            {templates.map((item,index) => (
                <TemplateCard
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    img={item.imgURL}
                    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                    index={index}
                    selected={selectedArray[index]==index? true:false}
                    handleClick={handleClick}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Now what's happening here is that we are using the index as an identifier, and based on that we are setting an array of selected cards. On the basis of which we send 'selected' prop to the Card component. And there you can apply your styling based on that prop.

Hope your question was answered!!